# Getting browser alert "Confirm navigation" with the choice to "Leave this page" or "stay on this page" on Woocommerce checkout

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

During checkout, when I submit the form, I get a alert "Confirm navigation", with the choice to "Leave this page" or "stay on this page". Don't know why I'm getting alert.

Anybody know about that issue, please help me.

Comment: Someone has an onbeforeunload event.

Comment: PLease clarify your question. What does "Why?" mean? "How did they do it?" - see epascarello's comment above (`onbeforeunload` event.) "For what reason?" - Because the developer chose to second-guess the user's choice to leave the page and does not care about annoying visitors.

Comment: I'm using Advanced Custom Field(ACF) in Woocommerce checkout page, but when I submit the order, I get an alert "Confirm navigation" with two choices "Leave this page" or "Stay on this page", when I click on "Leave this page" so it redirect me to Thank You Page.

Comment: @epascarello and fbitterlich Thanks your comments really helped me to solve this issue. I have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to remove "Confirm Navigation" alert dialog when submitting form on checkout.

```
jQuery('form.woocommerce-checkout').submit(function($) {
   jQuery(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});
```